# How do I add two arguments with nargs = '?' to a mutually exclusive group with Argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I have a program that can either save a plot as a png or pdf. I'd like the options `-s [path]` and `-S [path]`, where `[path]` is optional, and so if not given, the plot will be saved in the current working directory. This is the reason for `nargs = '?'`

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Mutually exclusive group example")
meg = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required = False)

meg.add_argument("-s", type = str, metavar = "path", help = "Save as png. If no path, will save to current working directory",
                 required = False, nargs = "?", default = None, const = None)

meg.add_argument("-S", type = str, metavar = "path", help = "Save as pdf. If no path, will save to current working directory",
                 required = False, nargs = "?", default = None, const = None)
```

When I execute the following:

```
args = parser.parse_args(("-s -S").split())
print(args)
```

It yeilds:

`Namespace(s=None, S=None)`

It is only when I specify a path for BOTH `-s` and `-S` that it raises an `ArgumentError`

How can I make sure only one of `-s` or `-S` are allowed regardless of if a path is specified. I've noticed that setting `const = True` works, so why doesn't `None` work?

Comment: I'd have to look at the code for the details, but since None is the default `default` it gets special handling. Normally `?` is used as a 3 'way' argument, yielding either the default, the const, or the user value.  Anyways I'm not surprised that the MEG group isn't catching it, but can't give the exact details (from memory).

Comment: The parse maintains two lists, `seen` and `seen_non_default`. One is used to test for `required`, and the other for mutually_exclusive.  So the `const` has to be different from the `default` to register as 'seen'.

Comment: To put @hpaulj's comment another way, your current code doesn't differentiate between `.parse_args(['-s'])`, `.parse_args(['-S'])`, and `.parse_args([])`.

Comment: Beside the point, but you don't need to specify the default values: `type=str`, `required=False`, and `default=None`.

Comment: Without getting into details of how the group testing is done, the `const` and `default` parameters need to be different from each other for each argument in the group.